# How can i convert Integer value to decimal value?

Tags: java, integer-division

i have an Integer value:

```
Integer value = 56472201;
```

Where the value could be positive or negative.

When I divide the value by 1000000, I want this result in the form `56.472201` but instead it gives me just the quotient. How am I able to get both the quotient and remainder values?

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: What is the result used for ? Do you want to just display it, or do you want to make other computations (and with what precision) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

cast it to float and then do it:

```
int i = 56472201;

float j = ((float) i)/1000000.0
```

Edit: Due to precision(needed in your case), use double. Also as pointed by Konrad Rudolph, no need for explicit casting:

```
double j = i / 1000000.0;
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, that cast is redundant when you divide by a `float` anyway (or in your case `double` for almost all languages).

Comment: Good point, I'm just an insecure/paranoid programmer (scared of strtok!)

Comment: thank u guyes It works with both @Konrad Rudolph @lalli and @Guffa  Thanks for the solutions

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the value to a floating point type first, otherwise you will be doing an integer division.

Example in C#:

```
int value = 56472201;
double decimalValue = (double)value / 1000000.0;
```

(The cast is actually not needed in this code, as dividing by a floating point number will cast the value to match, but it's clearer to write out the cast in the code as that is what actually happens.)

Answer (score 1):

If you divide an int by a double you will be left with a double result as illustrated by this unit test.

```
@Test
public void testIntToDouble() throws Exception {
    final int x = 56472201;
    Assert.assertEquals(56.472201, x / 1e6d);
}
```

`1e6d` is `1 * 10^6` represented as a double