# Find Time Complexity and big O of following Code

Tags: java, algorithm, time, time-complexity, analysis

Find the time complexity and big O of following code.
I am confused about what will be the time complexity of if else statements and other bar(a) and foo(a) function. Some friends are saying its time complexity is O(n^2) and some says its time complexity will be O(n). I also think that the time complexity of the following code will be O(n) because there is a return statement in the for loops which will make the time of both foo and bar function as O(1) and main for loop will run n time so time complexity will be O(n).

// Sample Code

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; ++i){
        if(i%2 != 0){
            sum += foo(i , n) + foo(1+i , n);
        }
        else{
            sum += foo(i , n) + bar(i , n);
        }
    }    
}
```

-

```
static void bar(int a , int n){
for(int i=0 ; i<n ; ++i){
    for(int j=0 ; j< i ; ++j){
        return a*(i+j);
    }
  }
}
```

-

```
static void foo(int a , int n){
for(int i=0 ; i<n ; ++i){
        return a*i;
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i convert Integer value to decimal value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707731/how-can-i-convert-integer-value-to-decimal-value)

Comment: Check out this resource and then elaborate on exactly where you are stuck
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it

Comment: Sounds like homework. What have you tried so far? Share your thoughts. There do you get stuck?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not clear what the problem of the user exactly is. It also shows no effort to solve the problem itself.

Comment: Right, the complexity is O(n) because of the returns. But a super-duper optimizer might see that foo and bar always return 0 so that there is no use to execute anything !

Answer (score 1):

Since you expressed your algorithm using an iterative paradigm, all you have to do is count the number of operations.

The complexity of `bar` is `O(n^2)`, because you have `n * (n + 1) / 2` operations of the type "`add i, j, then multiply by a`".

The complexity of `foo` is `O(n)` (`n` operations of the type "`multiply by a`").

In your main loop, half of the operation will call `foo` twice, which yields `(n / 2) * n` operations which is `O(n^2)`.
The second half of the iterations will call `foo` then `bar`, which yields `(n / 2) * [n + n * (n + 1) / 2]` that is to say `0.25.n^3 + 0.75.n^2` which is `O(n^3)`.

Therefore, the overall complexity of your loop is `O(n^3)`. This is generally referred to as the *time* complexity of your algorithm (even though we counted the number of operations - the intuition behind it is to consider a set of unit of operations and acknowledge each of those will take a constant amount of time. In our case, we chose the arithmetic operations `+` and `*`).

We can also analyse your algorithm from the perspective of memory consumption. In your case, the memory consumed is constant whatever the value of `n` is. This is why we would say that the *space* complexity is `O(1)` with respect to `n`.

*Edit: I though the "premature" `return` in `foo` and `bar` was a typo. If you don't loop, then the complexity of `foo` and `bar` is `O(1)`, and your main loop is `O(n)`.*

Comment: Hy Alexandre Duriez there is an return statement in both foo and bar function ( in for loops ). So i think there time complexity should be O(1)

Comment: Ah right - I though it was just a mistake. If you don't loop, then yes the complexity of `foo` and `bar` is `O(1)`, and your main loop is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

`foo() -> O(n)` because it goes from `i = 0 -> n`:

[image]

`bar() -> O(n^2)` because it from `j = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n` which is `O(n^2)`, as follows:

[image]

For `main()` you are going from `i = 0 -> n`, and you are calling `foo(n)` twice every even value of `i`. You are also calling `foo(n)`, but thats `O(n)` which does is not the worst case, so we do not care.

Considering the worst case `bar(n)`, being called n/2 times (every other form 0 to n):

[image]